# How can I keep a row of a button and text from wrapping using multicol?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a series of rows consisting of a button and text, like so:

```
[Button] [Text]
[Button] [Text]
[Button] [Text]
...
```

When I apply the `multicol` class, they eventually wrap around, like so:

```
[Button] [Text]   [Button] [Text]
[Button] [Text]   ....
```

Unfortunately, in many cases, the button or the text gets broken in half when going into the next column. **Using "display: inline-block"** makes my buttons and text vary in size on different screen resolutions, and makes them spaced strangely.

What is the best way to keep the `[Button] [Text]` combination from breaking in the column, while keeping each `[Button] [Text]` combination equally spaced, and looking the same?

```css
.multicol {
  column-count:2;
  -moz-column-count:2;
  -webkit-column-count:2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Imagine 20-25 of these in a row -->
  <div class='multicol'>
     <div class='row'>
         <div class='col-xs-5'>
              <button class='btn btn-block' style='min-width: 100px;'>  (VARYING-LENGTH BUTTON NAMES HERE) </button>
          </div>
          <div class='col-xs-7'>
               <p> (VARYING-LENGTH DESCRIPTIONS HERE) </p>
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: To be clear, you tried using `display: inline-block` on `.row`, right? If so, why does it affect your text size? That seems strange. My first instinct is you should fix that problem, then use `inline-block`.

Comment: @cjl750 It does not affect my text size, but rather the spacing between the `Button` and `Text` is not consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, added `white-space: normal` to the `button` to override the default *nowrap* from bootstrap's `btn` class.

> Unfortunately, in many cases, the button or the text gets broken in
>   half when going into the next column. Using "display: inline-block"
>   makes my buttons and text vary in size on different screen
>   resolutions, and makes them spaced strangely.

Well, you can *avoid* the *breaking* to the next column by using:

```
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
page-break-inside: avoid; /* Firefox */
break-inside: avoid; /* IE 10+ */
```

> and makes them spaced strangely

Add `column-gap: 0` to remove the *default* column gaps.

```css
.multicol {
  column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
}

.multicol button {
  white-space: normal;
}

.multicol>.row {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  page-break-inside: avoid; /* Firefox */
  break-inside: avoid; /* IE 10+ */
}

/*for illustration*/
.multicol>.row>* {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Imagine 20-25 of these in a row -->
<div class='multicol'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-5'>
      <button class='btn btn-block' style='min-width: 100px;'>  (VARYING-LENGTH BUTTON NAMES HERE) </button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-7'>
      <p> (VARYING-LENGTH DESCRIPTIONS HERE) </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-5'>
      <button class='btn btn-block' style='min-width: 100px;'>  (VARYING-LENGTH BUTTON NAMES HERE) </button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-7'>
      <p> (VARYING-LENGTH DESCRIPTIONS HERE) </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-5'>
      <button class='btn btn-block' style='min-width: 100px;'>  (VARYING-LENGTH BUTTON NAMES HERE) </button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-7'>
      <p> (VARYING-LENGTH DESCRIPTIONS HERE) </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-5'>
      <button class='btn btn-block' style='min-width: 100px;'>  (VARYING-LENGTH BUTTON NAMES HERE) </button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-7'>
      <p> (VARYING-LENGTH DESCRIPTIONS HERE) </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-5'>
      <button class='btn btn-block' style='min-width: 100px;'>  (VARYING-LENGTH BUTTON NAMES HERE) </button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-7'>
      <p> (VARYING-LENGTH DESCRIPTIONS HERE) </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you can add in some *flexboxes* here to suit your case - see demo below:

```css
.multicol {
  column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
}

.multicol button {
  white-space: normal;
}

.multicol>.row {
  display: flex; /*NEW*/
  margin: 0; /*NEW*/
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  page-break-inside: avoid; /* Firefox */
  break-inside: avoid; /* IE 10+ */
}

.multicol p { /*NEW*/
  height: 100%;
}

/*for illustration*/
.multicol>.row>* {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Imagine 20-25 of these in a row -->
<div class='multicol'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-5'>
      <button class='btn btn-block' style='min-width: 100px;'>  (VARYING-LENGTH BUTTON NAMES HERE) </button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-7'>
      <p> (VARYING-LENGTH DESCRIPTIONS HERE) </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-5'>
      <button class='btn btn-block' style='min-width: 100px;'>  (VARYING-LENGTH BUTTON NAMES HERE) </button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-7'>
      <p> (VARYING-LENGTH DESCRIPTIONS HERE) </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-5'>
      <button class='btn btn-block' style='min-width: 100px;'>  (VARYING-LENGTH BUTTON NAMES HERE) </button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-7'>
      <p> (VARYING-LENGTH DESCRIPTIONS HERE) </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-5'>
      <button class='btn btn-block' style='min-width: 100px;'>  (VARYING-LENGTH BUTTON NAMES HERE) </button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-7'>
      <p> (VARYING-LENGTH DESCRIPTIONS HERE) </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-5'>
      <button class='btn btn-block' style='min-width: 100px;'>  (VARYING-LENGTH BUTTON NAMES HERE) </button>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-7'>
      <p> (VARYING-LENGTH DESCRIPTIONS HERE) </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```